# How to interpret effects with level constraints in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can someone explain what spells/other effects mean when they have a max level requirement.  For example (taken from [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Illusion_%28Skyrim%29)): "Illusion: Mayhem - Creatures and people up to Lv25 will attack anyone nearby for 60s."

As I understand this is a Master level spell (50+). I've also tried digging on how mob level work and as far as I can tell, unless a cap is hit, most of the time the mob will be same level as you when you first enter a dungeon (and always same level as you in the world).  So why would 50+ lvl player care that he has an illusion spell that works on mob up to level 25??

This was just an example. What triggered my question is the fact that I'm running around with Fury, which apparent works up to level 6.  I'm level 12 and few times I tried to use (yes, stealthed from far away) it, did did nothing but make everyone attack me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those illusion spells benefit from illusion perks which allow them to be cast on higher level creatures.  If you don't take those perks, the spells become useless.

Comment: If necromancy were still a seperate skill, I'd be training it here....  but it's worth it to note that just because you have an Illusion skill of 50+ doesn't mean you're level 50.  A dedicated Illusionist should get to Illusion 50 long before level 20.  Likewise for anyone that focuses on a single combat style or two.